# How to print characters with spaces as a string in C++

Tags: c++

The code is not giving desired output
when I type in a string example "**Ben Parker**", the output is "**Goodmorning, Ben**" and not the entire name("Ben Parker") what seems to be the problem?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <cstring>

int main() {
char your_name[20];

std::cout << "Enter your name: ";
std::cin >> your_name;
std::cout << "Goodmorning, ";
std::cout.write (your_name, strlen(your_name)) << std::endl;

return 0;
}
```

---

**SOLUTION**

This was a very old question when I just began programming. 
The entire character array can be read and printed with a for loop, or better a `string` type variable can be used, since it is C++.

using `string your_name;`  seems to fix the problem, which can be then printed with a simple `std::cout << your_name << endl;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably put a space in between "Ben" and "Parker" in input. This would cause the `cin` logic to believe it had an answer after seeing the space following "Ben". You will probably want to read an entire line at a time to get past that problem. See [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/) page for an example.